# Загрузка файла на сервер импользуя адресную строку

Tags: php, fileupload

Собственно никогда с этим не сталкивался и интересуюсь реально ли это вообще...

Возможно ли некое вбить в адресную строку браузера, при этом вызвать автоматическую загрузку файла на сервер с компа?

1. Реально ли это
2. Как будет вылядеть само это **некое**
3. Возможно ли в принципе отправить файл на сервак не используя форму?

З.Ы. Я сам порой офигеваю от своих желаний которое должно испонлить железо, но все же!

З.Ы. Повтороное: Желательно на php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через адресную строку никак, так как параметры в адресной строке - это GET-параметры, а загружаемые файлы - FILES-параметры (в кратце). Обычно в Linux окружении для этого используют curl. В php также можно использовать curl. Гуглить по фразе php curl upload file. На первой странице обязательно будет решение.

Comment: @Drakmail в кусре я этого всего, я именно рассчитывал на чтото высокоподобное)

не зря и написал по поводу желаний которое должно испрлнять железо)

Comment: @Palmervan, даже `"input[type=file]"` защищены от автозаполнения, а вы хотите, чтоб страничка сразу предлагала залить жизненно необходимый для авторизации `NT.DLL`?)